# How does one import in python if the filename or filepath contains a non-alpha, non-underscore character?

Tags: python, import, special-characters

I need to import a function from a file which is in a folder whose name contains a special character, with the file itself also containing a special character. I cannot change the names to correct the issue. How does one perform the importation in such a situation?

Comment: In this case, the filepath goes through a folder called 'Instrument-Control' and the filename is 'audio$pecial'. I did not make these, but I must use them, and I cannot change the names. I wanted the question to be general so I did not put this info in the main request.

Comment: Please, no 'kill the guy who did this' comments.

Comment: You could try using `audiospecial = __import__("Instrument-Control.audio$pecial")`, but I don't know that that will work. Try roundly berating whoever did decide on the naming.

Comment: "I must use them, and I cannot change the names."  False.  Just change the names and move on.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yeah that is some horrible naming, but this should work for you:

```
Instrument_Control = __import__("Instrument-Control.audio$pecial")
audiospecial = getattr(Instrument_Control, "audio$pecial")
print audiospecial
# <module 'Instrument-Control.audio$pecial' from 'Instrument-Control/audio$pecial/__init__.py'>
audiospecial.example_func()  # executes example_func() from audio$pecial
```

Comment: If using Python 2.7 (or 3.1+), using `importlib.import_module` instead of `__import__` should simplify that a bit. The first two lines would be replaced by `audiospecial = importlib.import_module("Instrument-Control.audio$pecial")`

Comment: @ncoghlan I got "ImportError: Import by filename is not supported." for importlib.import_module('youtube-dl/youtube_dl') but it worked with importlib.import_module('youtube_dl', 'youtube-dl')

Comment: The first version might work with `importlib.import_module('youtube-dl.youtube_dl')` (replace `/` with `.`).